# How to process XML in CDATA section?

Tags: java, xml

I have this XML part:

```
<additionalChargeAttrs><![CDATA[
    <CPEChargeAttrs>
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Total charge amount" value = "99.00000000"/>
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Minimum number of installments" value = "3"/>  
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Maximum number of installments" value = "3"/>  
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Installment number" value = "1"/>
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Prorated from date" value = "1960-01-01 19:50:00"/>
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Prorated to date" value = "2020-12-31 19:50:00"/>
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Bundle code" value = " "/>
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Offer subtype" value = "P"/>
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "Installment eligibility" value = "Y"/>
         <complexattributeinfo name =  "NRC charge type" value = "Regular"/>
    </CPEChargeAttrs>
]]></additionalChargeAttrs>
```

I want to change the value of the following element (in CDATA section) to 3 using JAVA code:

```
<complexattributeinfo name =  "Installment number" value = "1"/>
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: -1 for ASAP/urgent...

Answer (score 1):

The content of the CDATA section is unparsed, meaning that it is just text blob. You need to take that text blob and run it through the XML parser again, change the attribute value, write the document to a new string, and replace the original CDATA content with this new string.